# How to make an object viewable in print layout only

Tags: google-docs

I'm creating a Google Docs template, and I'd like to set content in the header and footer that is only viewable in print layout (and when the doc is printed or exported to PDF), but is not visible when "print layout" is unchecked. How can I do this?

[image: print layout]

I searched the web for “make google docs object viewable in print mode only -word” and got no relevant results.

Comment: Please add a brief description of your search/research efforts as is suggested in [ask].

Answer (score 0):

When creating a proper "header" or "footer" by clicking "insert" > "header & page number" > (choose header or footer), Content in it is only viewable in print mode.

[Google documentation - Add or remove headers, footers & page numbers](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/86629?hl=en&ref_topic=9045931)